# divide by 0 problem vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, dataset

How Can I make sure PCTofSales, is not 0.

```
  'gets the projected sales by dividing the currentsales by the percent of sales
    Dim projectedye As New DataColumn
    projectedye = New DataColumn("ProjSales", GetType(Double))
    projectedye.Expression = "CurrentSales / (PCTofSales)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5:

```
pctofsales.Expression = "IIF([YEsales] = 0, 0, [ASOFSales] / [YEsales])"
```

See here:[MSDN's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for information about functions you can use inside the expression.

Comment: Should be IF not IIF ? IF only evaluates one of its arguments. IIF evaluates both.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use an IF THEN to call the function when:

"[ASOFSales] / [YEsales]"

equals zero or is inappropriate to divide?

Comment: i tryed, but i can't seem to get it, because the data is in a datacolumn so i am having a hard time

Comment: somewhere in there you can use an if then.  you could test the individual values if you had to and make a decision.  your head doesn't hurt *that* much does it? :)

Comment: yeah the problem is the if then statements don't work i will post them

Answer (score 0):

Run an update on your dataset to change all 0's to NULLs OR change your datasource to return NULLs instead of 0s in the PCTofSales/other column(s).